# Prove that the sequence $(y_n)$ converge to $0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ and let $m\in\mathbb N$. Define $y_n:=x_{n+m}-x_n$. Prove that the sequence $(y_n)$ converge to $0$.

I have to use epsilon-delta definition to prove this, and I am given the hint: triangle inequality. Can anyone some me some idea? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean $m\in \mathbb N$ instead?

Comment: You are right. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence of $x_n$ to a limit $x$ is stated as

$\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists N \left( \varepsilon \right)>0$, $\forall n > N
\left( \varepsilon \right)$, $\left| x_n - x \right| < \varepsilon$

Now for any integer $m$ defining $(y_n)$, fix $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and choose $n > N \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\right)$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \left| y_n \right| & = & \left| x_{n + m} - x_n \right|\\
  & = & \left| x_{n + m} - x - \left( x_n - x \right) \right|\\
  & < & \left| x_{n + m} - x \right| + \left| x_n - x \right|\\
  & < & \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_{n+m}-x_n)\\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n+m}-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n\\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Good, but not the kind of answer OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the limit of the convergent sequence, and figure out how to apply the triangle inequality to $L$, $x_n$, and $x_{m+n}$. By the way, your question doesn't make sense; $m$ must be an integer, not a real.

Comment: Sorry, I mean $m\in\mathbb N$.